# Как правильно организовать вызов асинхронной функции?

Tags: node.js, callback

Есть некоторая функция, у нее есть параметры, как правильно организовать её вызов в цикле с разными параметрами (на каждой итерации - новые параметры)?

Абстрактный пример:

```
while(id < N){
  bd.request('users.get', {'user_id' : id}, function(_o) {
    console.log(_o);
  });
id++;
}
```

Делаю так - виснет (циклится). Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Или с помощью сторонней библиотеки, например, `async`.

```
var async = require("async");
var calls = [];
while(id < N){
  calls.push(bd.request.bind(bd, 'users.get', {'user_id' : id++}));
}
async.series(calls, function(err, results){
  //тут работаете с результатами
});
```

Или с помощью Promise (в node 0.12+ появилась их родная поддержка, для более старых версий можно воспользоваться сторонней библиотекой)

```
function request(path, data){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    bd.request(path, data, function(err, res){
      if(err) return reject(err);
      resolve res;
    });
  });
}

var calls = [];
while(id < N){
  calls.push(request('users.get', {'user_id' : id++}));
}
Promise.all(calls).then(function(results){
  //тут работаете с результатами
});
```

Comment: а у меня же функция с callback vk.request('users.get', {'user_ids' : 1, 'fields' : 'schools', 'access_token' : 'b272fbfa2127c76fe267b5c9a3827ffece97f3b7fcc6fc7da834d34f66286c54dc84a6fb6190b5ced8e7c'}, function(_o) {
var res1 = JSON.stringify(_o);
var obj = JSON.parse(res1);
console.log(obj);
});